# A bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (not sending to dataOutput)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been automating some, and got a problem when migrating from 2.7 to 3.7. The code is as shown

```
def writeDataToOutput(dataOutput):
  global myUartPort
  global mySocket
  if (m_UseRTT):
    try:
      mySocket.sendall(dataOutput)
    except socket.error:
      print('Send failed')
  else:
    myUartPort.write(dataOutput)
```

And when running i get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monkeytest.py", line 1324, in <module>
    executeScript()
  File "monkeytest.py", line 1255, in executeScript
    if executeCommandLine(line) == 0:
  File "monkeytest.py", line 1159, in executeCommandLine
    executeCommand(commandPayload, 1, 1)
  File "monkeytest.py", line 587, in executeCommand
    writeDataToOutput(command + "\r\n")
  File "monkeytest.py", line 309, in writeDataToOutput
    mySocket.sendall(dataOutput)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I cannot see the wrong in my method, I have tried sendto() without any success.

Comment: Like the error says send all needs a bytes object not a string. This changed between 2 and 3 as in 2 it use to take a string. So now you would have to do like `mySocket.sendall(dataOutput.encode())` to get a bytes like object.

Comment: To build on what @ChrisDoyle is saying. In Python2.7, strings are by default Bytes. In Python3 they are by default Unicode, and if you need a bytes-like object, you will need to use the `str.encode()` method. If you then need to translate a Bytes-object back to Unicode, you can use `str.decode()`.